# Cant find specific class component using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a scraper for a cinema website to collect a list of movies names.
I've tried to use BeautifulSoup in order to parse the HTML file, I saw that each movie is inside a class named `"movie-row"`. But using the `select` method over this class didn't retrieve the corresponding data of the site. The closest component of the HTML that I was able to get was a parent class of `.quickbook-section`.

Why do some of the HTML tags are available using BS and other isn't?

This is the code I've written to do it.

```
def get_movies_names():
    url = "https://www.yesplanet.co.il/#/buy-tickets-by-cinema?in-cinema=1025&at=2018-11-09&view-mode=list"
    raw_html = util.simple_get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    bs.select(".movie-row")
```

(`simple_get` is just a function that return the HTML response content)

Comment: BS can't handle JavaScript, you might be running into this problem where some of the site is loaded through JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that particular website is rendering it's movie data using JavaScript.

Beautiful soup isn't a browser, thus is has no DOM so cannot run JavaScript code. All it does is fetch the page contents and parse it. If you view the source of the page in question and view source (right click, "View Source" in most browsers) and search for `.movie-row` you'll find there are no matches.

In this case you'll have to find an alternative to scraping the data, try investigating what the JavaScript code it uses does and go from there. Alternatively, you might want to look at using Selenium and PhantomJS.

Answer (score 4):

As some folks have indicated, it's being loaded via javascript and BS4 doesn't really work with that. When you see data that is loaded via javascript, you can bet there's an API call somewhere. Rather than trying to scrape data, you can look and see if it's calling for a JSON object and if you can access the JSON object without any apikey.

You might need to tweak some of the URL patterns if you need something different.

```
import requests, json
# Ignore the insecure warning
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://www.yesplanet.co.il/il/data-api-service/v1/poster/10100/by-showing-type/SHOWING?lang=he_IL&ordering=desc"

# Get the page
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

# Load into json
j = json.loads(response.text)

# process what you want
for poster in j['body']['posters']:
    print(poster['url'], poster['featureTitle'])
```

The output from the script is as follows:

```
/films/bohemian-rhapsody רפסודיה בוהמית
/films/the-other-story סיפור אחר
/films/the-girl-in-the-spiders-web הנערה ברשת העכביש
/films/the-nutcracker-and-the-four-realms מפצח האגוזים  וארבע הממלכות
/films/911 11 בספטמבר
/films/virgins אין בתולות בקריות
```

The available attributes for each poster are `attributes`, `code`, `dateStarted`, `featureTitle`, `mediaList`, `posterSrc`, `url`, and `weight`.

If you're wondering how I discovered the URL, I used the chrome developer console and reloaded the page. Filter on XHR (XMLHttpRequest) and you'll see URLs that have data.